# compare a network with multi value of a variable

Tags: netlogo

I have a network and simulate it in netlogo.In my network i have n nodes with a random data from [0.1,2,...,19].
at the beginning one random node became sink and 3 random nodes start to send its data to sink.i declare a variable named gamma.after nodes send their data to sink,sink decide to whether store that data in its memory space or not base on gamma.after 0.5s this process repeat.at each time some nodes are sink and want some data.this is the way i distribute data in my network.

after all i have to change gamma from 0 to 1 to determine best value for that. and each time run my code to plot count of something.i mean:first run my code with gamma=1 and after run it again with gamma=0.98 and ...

```
if Entropy <= gamma
[
do something
]
```

If i press the setup button each time i change gamma my network setup change and i can not compare the same network with another gamma.
How can i compare my network with multi value of gammas??
I mean is that possible to save all my process and run it exaclly the same again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `random-seed` to always create the same network and then use a new seed (created and set with `random-seed new-seed`) to generate the random numbers and ask order etc for your processing. The tool BehaviorSpace will allow you to do many runs with different values of gamma.

Using this approach will guarantee you the same network. However, just because a particular value of gamma is best for one network, does not make it the best for other networks. So you could create multiple networks with different seeds and have NetLogo select each network (as @David suggests) or you could simply allow NetLogo to create the different networks and run many simulations so that you have a more robust answer that works over an 'average' network.

Comment: I don't see a use for `with-local-randomness` here. After creating the network with a fixed random-seed, you can switch to different-each-time for the rest of the run with `random-seed new-seed`.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you design some tests first, when you put random data each time you press setup the previous graph is not the same as the new one, thus you'll need to load the same data everytime you want to test.

An idea:

Make text files with the node data and the value of gamma. For 4 nodes you'd have something like:

**dat1.txt**

```
1 3 2 9
1
```

**dat2.txt**

```
1 3 2 9
0.98
```

**dat3.txt**

```
1 3 2 9
0.96
```

And so on...

You can genereate this files with a procedure and an specific seed (see [random-numbers](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#random)), this means that if you want to generate 30 tests (30 sets of 4 nodes in the above example), you'll need 30 different seeds.